# Common words that cause topic overlap in gensim LDA

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, lda, topic-modeling, pyldavis

When we visualize the LDA using pyLDAvis, we can see topic overlap. I want know the word that is causing this topic overlap. Or I want to know the words that are at the intersection of the topic bubbles. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: By "seeing topic overlap", do you mean that projections of topics have an intersection e.g. topics 2 and 5 in this image? https://miro.medium.com/max/4832/1*k0svin9aq0ObRnHZgg6mFQ.png

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select topic 2
2. Copy a list of words from the right (the ones with bars)
3. Select topic 5
4. Copy the list as in 2.
5. Compare the copied lists on your own.

I am not sure there is any better method there...

Comment: Without using the interface (and copy/pasting) you could also imagining just doing the same with topics word distribution. Comparing top-100 words per topic...

Comment: isnt it possible that top 100 words might not have the overlap...

Comment: Depending on the training parameters but I would assume that there should be overlap among top 100 word sets if the topics overlap.